# Evaluating Z Score from Log Transformed Data

Tags: logistic, normalization, z-score

Lets say I have a set of data as below

```
set.seed(1075)
n <- 10000
x <- rnbinom(n, 1000, .5)
mean(x) 
-> 1000.1
sd(x) 
-> 45.167
```

If I wanted to get a Z-score on this data, I would use the regular formula:

```
Z = (X - MU) / SD
```

However, If I was to transform my random variables is the interpretation of the Z score the same?

```
lx <- log(x)
mean(lx)
-> 6.906834
sd(lx) 
-> 0.04519972
```

Is still 68% percent of the transformed data still between:

```
xbar +/- (1 * SD)
```

Or does the evaluation and computation of the Z score change with log transformed data?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reason this out and get to a "yes" answer, or you could just compute it.  Add the following to your code:

```
# proportion within 1 sd on original scale
sum(x > (mean(x)-sd(x)) & (x < mean(x)+sd(x)))  #6837


# proportion within 1 sd on log scale
sum(lx > (mean(lx)-sd(lx)) & (lx < mean(lx)+sd(lx)))  #6837
```

and they are identical.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I was correct, and this was a good second set of eyes on the problem. Cheers